# Getting undefined is not a function

Tags: coffeescript, stripe-payments

Using coffeescript to call out to Stripe and getting `undefined is not a function` on this line: `$.StripeJS.stripeResponseHandler($form)`

I have also tried:
`@.stripeResponseHandler($form)`
-and-
`StripeJS.stripeResponseHandler($form)`

Code:

```
class StripeJS
  constructor: (formId) ->
    @.setStripeResponseHandlerForForm(formId)

  stripeResponseHandler = (status, response, $form) ->
    console.log 'In stripeResponseHandler'

    if (response.error)
      #Clear the errors on the form
      $form.find('.payment-errors').html ''
      #Show the errors on the form
      $form.find('.payment-errors').append ('<div class="alert alert-error">
          <a class="close" data-dismiss="alert">×</a>
          <li>' + response.error.message + '</li>
        </div>')
      $form.find('button').prop 'disabled', false
    else
      # response contains id and card, which contains additional card details
      # Insert the token into the form so it gets submitted to the server
      $('#stripe_card_token').val response.id
      # and submit
      $form.get(0).submit()

  setStripeResponseHandlerForForm: (formId) ->
    Stripe.setPublishableKey $('meta[name="stripe-key"]').attr('content')
    $("#{formId}").submit (event) ->
      console.log 'In setStripeResponseHandlerForForm'
      $form = $(this)
      # Disable the submit button to prevent repeated clicks
      $form.find('button').prop 'disabled', true

      console.log 'About to call out to Stripe'
      Stripe.createToken $form, (status,response) ->
        $.StripeJS.stripeResponseHandler($form)
      console.log 'Back from calling stripe'
    # Prevent the form from submitting with the default action
      return false

$(document).ready ->
  $.StripeJS = new StripeJS('#new_agent')
```

Comment: You haven't defined $.StripeJS yet. It is still in the process of being constructed.  That's why you get an error. If you can trace through to ensure you don't get an error during the construct.

Comment: @MiltoxBeyond So the document ready section `$(document).ready ->
  $.StripeJS = new StripeJS('#new_agent')` does not actually instantiate it?

Comment: Probably not, you have to debug to see if it does actually store it.  You can probably simplify the constructor to not call setStripeResponseHandlerForForm.  Then after you've created $.StripeJS, call $.StripeJS.setStripeResponseHandlerForForm('#new_agent'); By then it should be defined...